# Axios not showing informations on react page

Tags: reactjs, axios

I would like to use axios to fetch the values from API in react.js, and set it as a form, but it doesn't display any fetched data at all.

```
export default function Review() {

  const [fetchedData, setFetchedData] = useState([]);
  const [fetchedlanguage, setlanguage] = useState([]);


     useEffect(() => {
       const getStudent = async () => {
         const stu = await axios.get('http://localhost:8000/students/');
         setFetchedData(stu.data.students[0]);
         setlanguage(stu.data.students[0].languages)
       };
       getStudent()
     },[]);

     console.log("student: ", fetchedData);

    const [formdata, setformdata] = useState({
        availability: 6,
        preference:'201, 301',
        experience:'201',
        language:fetchedlanguage[0],
        background:fetchedData.background,
    });
```

Even though the console.log shows the data correctly, when I set the form here, how come there is no updates on data?

Comment: state in react is asynchronous, which means that the data MAY not be retrieved yet when you go to set the data in your `useState` call - in that call check to see IF the data is or isnt null, and then proceed accordingly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Control it all in one place. You will want to spread the original values over the setformdata because it's immutable. I'm not sure what all the API returns so continue to override each formdata property that you get back from the API.

```js
export default function Review() {
    const [formdata, setformdata] = useState({
        availability: 6,
        preference:'201, 301',
        experience:'201',
        language: 'english',
        background: 'initial-background',
    });

    useEffect(() => {
        const getStudent = async () => {
            const stu = await axios.get('http://localhost:8000/students/');
            const student = stu.data.students.length > 0 ? stu.data.students[0] : {};
            setFormData({
                ...formdata,
                langauge: student.languages,
                // TODO: continue to override the formData from student returned from API
            });
        };
        getStudent()
    }, []);

    // TODO: use formdata to feed into form
    return null;
}
```